# Provide an Objective-C compatibility to non-compliant Swift types

Tags: swift, objective-c, bridging-header

I am trying to understand what would be a good pattern for providing an Objective-C compatibility to non-compliant Swift types.

Consider the following example:

```
class Model {
    var b: Bool? // Optional Bool cannot be marked as @objc
    var i: Int? // Optional Int cannot be marked as @objc
    var e: MyEnum // Swift enums, except for Integer type, cannot be marked as @objc
}
```

My current naive implementation is:

```
extension Model {
    @objc func setB(_ value: Bool) { b = value }
    @objc func unsetB() { b = nil }
    @objc var isB: NSNumber? { guard let b = b else {return nil }; return NSNumber(value: b) }
}
```

That works, but with many properties, this is very tedious to define, and even worse on usage from Objective-C (while in Swift all properties can be provided on `init`, in Objective-C they would have to be set / unset one by one).

So are there any better patterns to provide an Objective-C compatibility to the properties of non-compliant Swift types?

Any tips are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What about adding an `init` that takes an `NSNumber` parameter for each optional `Bool` or `Int`?

Comment: @HangarRash that has another limitation: they would have to provide _all the parameters_ (since default arguments are not translated from swift to objc). I.e. if I have `init(b: Bool? = true)` it becomes `initWithB:` on objc and they have to provide a value for `b` - not quite convenient either. I guess I will have to have something like a builder pattern interface...